# How Cacti stores SNMP data?

Tags: rrdtool, cacti

I have been investigating how [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) stores data retrieved via SNMP. From my observation, they seem to use the third party graphing tool [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) which reads the data directly from flat files (.rrd files) instead of a database. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

Qoute from [cacti.net:](http://www.cacti.net/what_is_cacti.php)

> Graphs Once one or more data sources are defined, an RRDTool graph can
>   be created using the data. Cacti allows you to create almost any
>   imaginable RRDTool graph using all of the standard RRDTool graph types
>   and consolidation functions. A color selection area and automatic text
>   padding function also aid in the creation of graphs to make the
>   process easier.

They made it easier by having configuration to RRDTool made through a GUI.

[More on features](http://www.cacti.net/features.php)